# Analog to $.map that loops over an object's properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery offer an analog to `$.map` that loops over an object's properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.6, `$.map` not only iterates over arrays but also over the properties of an object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: +1, it's worth noting that you can eliminate the "hasOwnProperty" check if you want to include inherited properties.

Comment: none of these are really a 'map' function, they are more like $.each (which works on objects and their properties btw)